# Correct way to configure the lastest `org-mode` (literate programming)

Tags: org-mode, init-file, debugging, literate-programming

**Update: 11/Aug**: I forgot to mention that I'm using literate programming to build the `init.el` from an `org` file. It seems that the problem appears when emacs opens the `configure.org` to generate the `.el` file.

I noticed that if I write the configuration to a `.emacs` (as I wrote below) the right version is loaded.

**The right question**

How to load the latest version of `org-mode` using `org` literate programming to generate the `config.el` file?

---

I'd like to use the latest version of `org-mode` from the git repository.

### My setup

*Emacs version:* GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) of 2015-03-07 on trouble, modified by Debian

### About org-mode

- I clone the repository, say in `~/.emacs.d/org-mode`
- Compile the autoload using `make autoload`
- Initial part of my `.emacs` is

  ```el
  (package-initialize)

  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/")
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-mode/contrib/lisp/" t)

  (unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-install 'use-package))

  (setq use-package-verbose t)
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t)

  (require 'use-package)

  (use-package auto-compile
    :config (auto-compile-on-load-mode))

  (setq load-prefer-newer t)
  ```

### Result

I call `M-x org-version` and get

> Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /home/.../.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/)

This is no the latest release!

If I call `M-x org-reload` it load the newest

> Org-mode version 8.3.5 (release_8.3.5 @ /home/.../.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp/)

But it is not loaded automatically.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong??

P.D.: I accept suggestions about simplifying the configuration.

Comment: I've had similar problems and don't know the solution. But other org lisp files probably exist on your system? Like under `/usr/share`?

Comment: I split my .emacs config into 2 parts: 1) package setup into normal .el config 2) other setup into org literate files, and load them after 1) using `babel-loader`.

Comment: Do you have org-mode package installed twice?

Answer (score 1):

You have still not provided the real initialization code, but from your description it seems, your `.emacs` contains code that loads an org-file for example with `org-babel-load-file`.

To use this function org-mode has to be loaded and because it's part of emacs, this doesn't raise a chicken-and-egg problem, but succeeds with the builtin version. And because org-mode now is loaded it will never be looked up in your cloned directory that is configured after this point.

Starting from this insight you have at least these possibilities:

### Tangle your org-file

Just tangle the `.emacs` or `init.el` every time you change your source file. There is for sure a way to do this automatically.

### Bootstrap org-mode before loading the init-file

Move the loading of org-mode to `.emacs` and then `org-babel-load-file` the rest of your configuration.

### reload org-mode

Reload org-mode in the above shown code with `org-reload`.  I think this is the least useful choice because org-mode is loaded twice.

Comment: I have the same problem, but could you please make your answer more useful by adding some code in `init.el` for each case scenario?